# How two detect that the same users authenticated from different network?

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET forms authentication, is it possible to detect that two of the same login logged in?

I want this to prevent a situation that two users on the same account modify the same thing. so i want to notify the user that another user of the same login name is already inside the system.

I am also using MemberShip model of .net to authenticate if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this resource](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030418.asp).  This approach uses the cache to see if the user has made a login request on another machine.  I've seen the database also used as well.  The main goal is check to see if the user has gone through the login process, and if they have, block the second attempt to login.

Comment: looks promising , i will check it.